# Use of the Simple Pluperfect

Tags: português-europeu

Ando a aprender Português há 18 meses, mas tenho duas perguntas:

**1. What is the use of the *Simple* Pluperfect in spoken & written Portuguese?**

**2. Additionally, why is it that the Compound Pluperfect (also known as the 'Past Perfect') is preferred over the Simple Pluperfect, when in fact, the latter is incredibly easy to form? For example:**

(The below examples use the *Simple Pluperfect*):

> a) Não comprei gelado, pois, eu já **comprara** bolo na noite anterior.
>
> b) Ele não precisava de cozinhar mais frango, porque a sua esposa já **cozinhara** ao chegar na casa.

(The below examples use the *Compound Pluperfect / Past Perfect*):

> a) Não comprei gelado, pois, eu já **tinha comprado** bolo na noite anterior.
>
> b) Ele não precisava de cozinhar mais frango, porque a sua esposa já **tinha cozinhado** ao chegar na casa.

Thanks much for your responses in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The good thing about the *simple* pluperfet, *pretérito mais-que-perfeito*, and the *normal* pluperfect, *mais-que-perfeito composto* from the learner's point of view is that they mean the same.

The *simple* pluperfect is hardly ever used in informal speech. Some people may even not feel confident in using it. And the *normal* pluperfect can be used even in formal language. The *simple* pluperfect is most common in literature.

Perhaps the most common use of the *mais-que-perfeito simples* in common speech is in **three idiomatic expressions**, where in fact it is not used as *mais-que-perfeito* at all: *pudera, quem me dera,* and *tomara (eu), tomaras tu, tomáramos nós*, etc. Credit to Artefacto who thought about it first.

[**Pudera**](http://www.dicio.com.br/pudera/) is an interjection meaning *it couldn’t be otherwise! What else would you expect?!*

> “O Pedro foi despedido.” ─ “Pudera! O patrão apanhou-o a roubar dinheiro da caixa.” (“Pedro was sacked.” – “Pudera! The boss caught him stealing from the till.”)

[**Quem me dera**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/quem%20dera) means *I wish, I’d love* (something that’s not going to happen):

> Quem me dera ter um cão! Mas vivo num apartamento pequeno e teria que o deixar sozinho o dia todo. (I’d love to have a dog! But I live in a small flat, and would have to leave it alone all day.)
>
> Quem me dera ser um pássaro! (I wish I were a bird!)

Lastly, [**tomara**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tomara) is an interjection meaning *I hope, I wish, I’d love, I'll be happy if*:

> Vamos fazer um picnic amanhã. Tomara que não chova. (We're going to have a picnic tomorrow. I hope it won't rain.)
>
> "O teu ex-namorado disse que iria chegar tarde."  ─ "Tomara eu que ele não viesse de todo." (Your ex-boyfriend said he would be late." "I'd be happy if he didn't turn up at all.")

Now, why do people use the compound pusperfect rather than the simple one. I don't know that, but iIn fact the compound pluperfect is easier. You only have to know the past participle of the main verb (the one you want to conjugate), and you have to know it anyway for other things, and the verb *ter*. You can also use the verb *haver* instead of *ter* as auxiliary: *ela havia cozinhado, tu havias feito*. It is fairly rare though.

There is also a little issue with the *simple* pluperfect: in the third person plural it is the same as the simple past, *pretérito perfeito*, which could possibly be confusing. Compare:

> Eles *encontraram-me* ontem, e contaram-me que te *tinham encontrado* no dia anterior.
> Eles *encontraram-me* ontem, e contaram-me que te *encontraram* no dia anterior.

The two sentences mean the same, but in the sencond you have the same word, *encontraram,* to convey different tenses for the same person. It does not lead to confusion in this case, but it migh be ambiguous in others.

Comment: You are right. I hadn't thought about the simplicity of the compound pluperfect.

Comment: "The simple pluperfect is hardly ever used in informal speech" I guess I get to continue being *that* guy haha.  But if used in speech, how does it come off?  Just sound more refined, or downright strange?  Any difference in northern Portugal where it seems the language is a bit more conservative (given Asturian and Galician both still use it in the spoken language, not sure about Mirandese).

Comment: That's an interesting question. I'll start using it around to see how people react. I can't really tell. I can't remember people using it, not even my northern friends. My guess is nobody would think less of you on account of it. Even though it sounds formal, your attitude and demeanour would be more important.

Comment: And addendum on Mirandese: it seems the simple form is also still used alongisde the compound.  A book on it gives AST: "Cuando nós lleguemos, él yá comiera", GL: "Cuando nós chegamos, el xa comera", PT: "Quando nós chegámos, ele já tinha comido" but MWL: "Quando nós cheguemos, el yá comira (also: tenie/había comido)"

Comment: It's perfectly ok to translate to PT "ele já comera," especially from a book.

Answer (score 9):

O mais-que-perfeito simples é usado quase exclusivamente na escrita. Quando é usado na oralidade, é-o geralmente como parte de certas expressões idiomáticas exclamativas com os verbos "dar", "poder", "tomar" ou (menos comum) "prazer". Nelas, o valor desta forma verbal é equivalente *não* ao pretérito mais-que-perfeito composto, mas sim ao pretérito imperfeito do subjuntivo:

- - Quem me **dera** ser rico! / - **Tomara** eu ser rico! (desejo)
- - **Tomaras** tu ter um corpinho como o meu! / Quem te **dera** (a ti) ter um corpinho  como o meu! (desejo que o locutor crê que o interlocutor deveria ter)
- - **Prouvera** a Deus! (=~ "oxalá")
- - Ele deixou de me falar... - **Pudera**, depois do que lhe fizeste! (não é de admirar; não podia ser de outra forma)

Sublinhe-se que se tratam de **expressões idiomáticas**. Os mesmos verbos usados no mais-quer-perfeito simples em frases com estruturas diferentes não teriam o mesmo significado de desejo (ou de falta de espanto, no caso de "pudera"). É provável que a maioria dos falantes nem sequer interiorizem estes usos como um mais-que-perfeito com valor de imperfeito do subjuntivo.

Tirando estas expressões idiomáticas, o valor de imperfeito do subjuntivo ouve-se ainda um pouco em outras situações, nomeadamente orações concessivas e condicionais (especialmente com "fora" e inversão sujeito-predicado):

- **Não fora** (=(se) não fosse) o dinheiro para comprar silêncios, e já andaria pelos tribunais a disputar a criança.

Finalmente, há [outros usos](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/comecaratinha-comecado/3292), mas estes são provavelmente ainda mais raros na oralidade do que o valor normal de passado anterior:

- Que **fora** (=seria) de ti, se eu não te aconselhasse?
- Não fossem as amizades que tem e já **fora** (=teria sido, tinha sido) despedido.

Até podemos combinar os vários valores:

- E se mais mundo **houvera** (=houvesse), lá **chegara** (=chegaria). (Camões, «Os Lusíadas», VII, 14).

Em todo o caso, o uso do mais-que-perfeito simples como imperfeito do conjuntivo e (especialmente) condicional pertence mais à esfera literária.

Quando ao uso "normal" para passado anterior ao tempo de referência, é algo que se ouve na televisão (especialmente no texto preparado para os pivôs), mas muito raramente no dia-a-dia. Admiti-lo-ia talvez mais em frases enfáticas com inversão:

- Nem nunca fizera eu (=tinha eu feito) tal coisa!

Em todo o caso, o melhor seria encontrar um estudo sobre este assunto ou analisar um corpus oral.

Passemos à escrita. Para o CETEMPúblico (textos jornalísticos), a distribuição é esta:

- **Composto com ter** (`[lema="ter" & temcagr="IMPF_IND"] [pos="V"]`): 74107 ocorrências.
- **Composto com haver** (`[lema="haver" & temcagr="IMPF_IND"] [pos="V"]`): 13017 ocorrências.
- **Simples** (`[temcagr="MQP_IND" & (word=".*ra" | word=".*ram" | word=".*ras" | word=".*reis" | word = ".*ramos")]`): 88184 ocorrências.

[image]

A anotação do CETEMPúblico está longe de perfeita, mas pelas amostras que vi > 90% dos resultados estavam bem anotados. Isto signfica que na escrita jornalística (não particularmente formal e não literária), o mais-que-perfeito simples é, se não a forma preferida, pelo menos tão usada como a forma composta com "ter" (com a ressalva de que não são sempre substituíveis). O top 5:

```
fora     20658
fizera   1871
foram    1696
acabara  1150
dera     1080
```

"Fora" é de longe a mais usada, representando mais de 20% dos resultados.

Comment: Esta resposta é de alta qualidade, mas não é adequada ao nível do perguntador.

Comment: @Artefacto interessante, não sabia que no português também a forma simples havía tomado o valor condicional.  Este uso considera-se fica no registro formal o deve ser evitado?

Comment: Muito interessante. Só acho duvidoso que _tomara_ e _pudera_ tenham o valor do pretérito do subjuntivo: _tomasses tu ter um corpinho como o meu? Pudesse, depois do que lhe fizeste?_ Nem com o DACL lhes consigo dar significado. O DACL classifica _tomara eu_ etc como função interjetiva. O Priberam também classifica _pudera_ como interjeição. Mas não me custa a crer que em tempos idos pudessem ser entendidos como pretérito do subjuntivo.

Comment: Olhai o que eu encontrei em três páginas da Peregrinação do Mendes Pinto: _como se isso lhe ouuera de ser matéria... como quem vira a morte_. Mas também _para que pudesse_. E já agora, _tinhão levado... tinha morto_.

Comment: @Jacinto Consigo perfeitamente analisar _pudera_ como imperfeito do subjuntivo (o que nao quer dizer que seja de facto essa a origem). Na minha frase: _Pudera!_ -> _Pudera (tal ser de outra forma)!_ -> _(Como se) pudesse (isso ser de outra forma)!_. O _tomara_ sempre vi como o espelho de _dera_: "quem me dera" -> "tomara eu", mas pensando melhor talvez seja um condicional. O problema é que é-me difícil perceber o que _tomar_ quer dizer, sendo um verbo com tantos significados mas pouco central hoje em dia.

Comment: @guifa Esse uso hoje em dia é mais do domínio da literatura (nem sequer formal). Era mais popular uns secúlos atrás.

Comment: @Artefacto Poderia adicionar uma tradução para o inglês? Se o OP fez as perguntas em inglês, é possível que ele não possa compreender toda a sua resposta em português.

Comment: @BrunoLopes Concordo. Apesar de eu entender algo da sua resposta, eu beneficiaria muito por ler uma tradução em Inglês também.

Comment: @Artefacto Parece-me que _pudera_ possa ter essa origem, mas duvido que muita gente interprete _pudera_ assim. Não é à toa que os dicionários o definem como interjeição. Acho que a tua resposta pode sugerir, a um falante não nativo, que _pudera, quem me dera, tomaras tu_ são exemplos dum uso mais geral na fala do pret. MQP desses verbos com com valor de pret. do conjuntivo, quando na verdade são expressões idiomáticas fixas.

Comment: @Jacinto Bom, eu digo "À parte de alguns usos fossilizados ... o uso ... como imperfeito ... pertence mais à esfera literária" (o que contradiz um pouco o que vem antes). Mas na verdade, nem tenho assim tanta certeza. Parece-me que em frases com inversão sujeito predicado (tal como com "dar", "prazer"), o MQPS tem alguma (mas não muita) produtividade na oralidade, quer com valor de MQP, quer com valor de imperfeito. "Soubera eu de que é que se tratava...", "Nem nunca dissera eu tal coisa".

Comment: Outra questão é se os falantes de facto interiorizam "o quem me dera" como um imperfeito. Não tenho a certeza, mas de facto talvez não.

Comment: Tou só a falar de _dar, poder, tomar_ em expressões exclamativas. Quando li os _usos fossilizados_ lá mais abaixo não interpretei isso como restringindo o uso desses verbos aos exemplos dados. E não se diz _dera-me ele atenção! Tomara ele os medicamentos! Pudera eu tomar conta dele!_ em vez de _desse-me ele atenção_, etc.

Comment: _Quem me dera_ é para mim a expressão mais inteligível: _houvesse alguém que me desse eu-ser-rico_.

Comment: @Jacinto Não sei sei estou a compreender bem a objeção. Com modalidade volitiva (portanto não como uma expressão condicional), diz-se tanto "Pudera eu tomar conta dele!" como "Pudesse eu tomar conta dele!" (i.e. não se diz). Seria preciso acrescentar um "ai" ou talvez um "como se" em ambos os casos. Queres dizer que as expressões com "dar" etc. têm um carácter volitivo que não se encontra em outras formas com o MQPS ou o subjuntivo propriamente dito?

Comment: Das três expressões idiomáticas, _pudera, tomaras tu, quem me dera_, a última é para mim a que melhor se compreende a partir do significado comum das palavras constituintes.