# Pretérito Mais-que-perfeito Simples vs Composto

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, verbos

Quando usamos pretérito mais-que-perfeito composto e quando o simples?

Pelo que eu percebi o pretérito mais-que-perfeito é equivalente o **past perfect** em inglês! Mas eu estou confuso sobre os formes simples e composto! Procurando no internet isso parece que o forma simples está usado raromente e mais na linguagem formal. Mas a forma composto está usada na linguagem informal. Sim?

Quais são as diferençao entre estas duas formas?

Comment: É exatamente como você encontrou - não há diferença de significado entre eles, só de uso.

Comment: @Majid, já tens [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/use-of-the-simple-pluperfect) com duas respostas sobre este assunto. Vê se esclarecem tudo o que queres saber. Se o fizerem podemos fechar esta como duplicata. Caso contrário, reformula a tua pergunta, focando os aspetos que queres saber e que não ficaram esclarecidos na outra pergunta.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim você tem razão. Já fechei!