# Qual é a origem de "tomara (que)" para expressar desejo?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões-idiomáticas, origem, interjeições

"**Tomara!**" é uma interjeição usada no português brasileiro para exprimir desejo (similar ao "oxalá!" do pt-PT) e, com o mesmo sentido, também pode ser usada em frases como:

- **Tomara que** ele perca.
- **Tomara que** seja verdade.
- **Tomara que** nada (de ruim) aconteça.

A única referência a origem desse uso que encontrei foi no site Origem da Palavra, onde [se afirma](https://origemdapalavra.com.br/palavras/tomara/) que a origem é desconhecida.

Em pt-PT a expressão mais próxima [seria](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/tomara-e-tomara-que/24783) "Tomara eu!". Talvez essa seja uma pista para a origem de "Tomara!" - e se poderia especular que o "tomara que" derivaria da interjeição. Mas seria interessante ter mais que especulações.

Comment: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1296/249 . `Tomara!` sozinho não se diz em Portugal, mas os outros exemplos também se podiam por cá encontrar.

Answer (score 5):

O [Novo dicionário da língua portuguesa](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31552/) de Candido de Figueiredo (1913) coloca (pg. 1965) como um dos significados que o verbo "tomar" admitia na época:

> Escolher. **Desejar**: tomara êlle que assim fôsse!

ou seja, "*Desejara/Quisera ele que assim o fosse!*".

E aqui esse "desejara" não assume o valor atual usual do pretérito mais-que-perfeito (de "passado do passado"), mas sim o de *condicional que indica desejo* ou aspiração, como [no exemplo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/uso-do-preterito-mais-que-perfeito/7932) "Quisera eu que tu estudasses." (em que quisera=quereria), um uso que [não se mantém](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-preterito-mais-que-perfeito-com-valor-condicional/26586) na linguagem coloquial atual.

Portanto, "**tomara que**" significava "**(eu) desejaria que**" ou, mais diretamente, "*desejo que*".